# Hard reset Sinch client in iOS

Tags: ios, ios9, sinch

Using latest Sinch client for messaging module is working pretty well.
Now I need a logout functionality. All is going smooth, except the Sinch client is not being hard reset and not getting messages as push notification. As a result, history is not being shown.

Comment: Sinch is like  the postman, we dont have an mailbox, we delive reach message once to each device for a user.

Comment: @cjensen i was asking regarding how sinch client knows he is installed in new app.

Comment: i just need to revert it to that state simple.

Comment: We save some data on the device to identify it,